# Different behavior on Xcode and xcodebuild

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I have a CI environment which builds my project. So when I compile my project with `xcodebuild -target MyTarget` and run it on a physical device, I get a visual bug with one of the `Three20` libraries as well as a reproducible crash.

However, when I compile and run the project and the same target via Xcode I neither have the crash nor the visual problem.

Since I don't do anything fancy with `xcodebuild` I would expect the two builds to be identical. Generally I'd rather have the problem in two places than the two builds behave differently.

Has anyone run into similar issues and how can I make sure that the product of Xcode and xcodebuild is identical? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Try comparing the build commands output from `xcodebuild` with the build transcript form within Xcode and see if there are any differences ?

Comment: Are you specifying a workspace for the xcodebuild and is it the same as the one you use with the Xcode GUI builds.

Comment: @ChrisGummer I am not explicitly using Workspaces so they should both use the same default workspace.

Comment: Xcode 4 will create the workspace for you, which is what you GUI builds will be using. I'd suggest specifying this workspace when running xcodebuild using the -workspace option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running `xcodebuild -scheme MyScheme`, where `MyScheme` is most likely the name of your target if Xcode auto-generated the scheme for you.

The GUI uses schemes when building and I've found that you can usually get the same behavior by specifying a scheme to `xcodebuild`.